# K-core graph algorithm on pyspark: iterative loop kills spark session

Tags: pyspark, graph, apache-spark-sql

I have other data, but I will give an example on a dataframe with k-core = 10

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(100, 100)
core = nx.k_core(G, 10)
if len(core) > 0:
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(core.edges()), columns=['source', 'target'])
graph = spark.createDataFrame(df)
```

Next, I want to count the number of incoming and outgoing edges (and join)

```
outgoing_edge = graph.groupby('source').agg(F.collect_set('target').alias('count_outgoin')) \


ingoing_edge = graph.groupby('target').agg(F.collect_set('source').alias('count_ingoin'))


ingoing_edge = ingoing_edge.withColumnRenamed("target", "source")

get_all_count_edge = outgoing_edge.join(ingoing_edge, on="source", how="outer") \
.withColumn("count_outgoin", F.coalesce(F.col("count_outgoin"), F.array()))\
.withColumn("count_ingoin", F.coalesce(F.col("count_ingoin"), F.array()))\
.withColumn("in_plus_out", F.array_distinct(F.flatten(F.array(F.col('count_outgoin'), F.col('count_ingoin')))))\
.withColumn('count_edge', F.size('in_plus_out'))\
.select('source', 'in_plus_out', 'count_edge') \
.cache()
get_all_count_edge.count()
```

And everything is the same only already in a cycle (since this is a k-core algorithm). I filter nodes that have edges less than k, and then remove such nodes (first join). The second join is needed to delete nodes whose edges have been removed. And I do it iteratively.At the end, I check that the number of unique nodes is more than one.

```
def k_core_alg( get_all_count_edge):
    k = 2
    dataframes = {}

    while True:
        print(f'=========== start k: {k} =========')
              
        get_all_count_edge_filter = get_all_count_edge.filter(F.col('count_edge') < k).select(F.col('source').alias('target'))
        print(f'        see edge < k      ')
        print(f'check count where edge < k: {get_all_count_edge_filter.count()}')
        
        graph = get_all_count_edge.filter(F.col('count_edge') >= k).withColumn('target',F.explode('in_plus_out')).select('source', 'target')
        print(f'        see edge > k      ')
        print(f'check count where edge > k (explode): {graph.count()}')
        
        graph = graph.join(F.broadcast(get_all_count_edge_filter), graph.target == get_all_count_edge_filter.target, 'left_anti')\
            .cache()
        print(f'        first join      ')
        print(f'count first join: {graph.count()}')
        
        
        outgoing_edge = graph.groupby('source').agg(F.collect_set('target').alias('count_outgoin'))
        
        
        ingoing_edge = graph.groupby('target').agg(F.collect_set('source').alias('count_ingoin'))\
        .withColumnRenamed("target", "source")

        get_all_count_edge = outgoing_edge.join(F.broadcast(ingoing_edge), on="source", how="outer") \
        .withColumn("count_outgoin", F.coalesce(F.col("count_outgoin"), F.array()))\
        .withColumn("count_ingoin", F.coalesce(F.col("count_ingoin"), F.array()))\
        .withColumn("in_plus_out", F.array_distinct(F.flatten(F.array(F.col('count_outgoin'), F.col('count_ingoin')))))\
        .withColumn('count_edge', F.size('in_plus_out'))\
        .select('source', 'in_plus_out', 'count_edge')
        
        print(f'        second join      ')
        print(f'second join: {get_all_count_edge.count()}')
        
        graph = get_all_count_edge.filter(F.col('count_edge') >= k).withColumn('target',F.explode('in_plus_out')).select('source', 'target')
        dataframes["prevgraph_" + str(k)] = graph
        
        count_check = graph.select('source').distinct().count()
        print(f'    count distinct users: {count_check}    ')

        if count_check <= 1:
            prev_k = k-1
            k_core_graph_max = dataframes["prevgraph_" + str(prev_k)] 
            break
        else:
            k += 1
                
    k_end = prev_k
    print(f'k-core = {k_end}') 
    return k_core_graph_max        

k_core_graph_max = k_core_alg(get_all_count_edge)
```

But the **problem** is that the more k the longer the spark processes, and in the end I get errors at all: `issue communicating with driver in heartbeater` and the spark session is killed.I do not understand why..

Note: I would like to write everything on the pyspark and I need a bunch of prints to understand at what point spark session dies

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried tweaking spark configuration - increasing spark network timeout or heartbeat interval? Also, inspect logs for running out of memory needed for doing the job. You might as well be in need of repartitioning.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you can change the spark parameters, but I would like to do it somehow using code